# Загрузка фотографий на сервер без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, upload, preview

Решил сделать загрузку файлов указанным способом https://habrahabr.ru/company/io/blog/257533/. Файлы успешно сохраняются на сервер с рандомными именами. Решил задачу усложнить созданием превьюшек для фотографий и возможностью удаления без перезагрузки. Но не могу решить вопрос с взаимодействием разных функций. По коду понятнее будет.

Есть `input`, который после выбора фотографий запускает функцию js

```
(function () {
var uploadfiles = document.querySelector('#uploadfiles');
uploadfiles.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var files = this.files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        uploadFile(this.files[i]);
    }

}, false);

function uploadFile(file){
    var url = "/upload";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(){
            $('.loader').show();
        }
        xhr.upload.onload = function() {
            $('.loader').hide();
            (function Notification() {
                var notification = new NotificationFx({
                    message : "<p>Фотография загружена</p>",
                    layout : "growl",
                    effect : "jelly",
                    type : "success",
                });
                notification.show();        
            })();
        }
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
        }
    };
    fd.append('uploaded_file', file);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
}());
```

Функция запускает php для обработки и загрузки файла на сервер и заносит значения в БД.

```
$photo = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$name = md5($photo) . '.jpg';
$dir = substr(md5(microtime()), mt_rand(0, 30), 2) . '/' .     substr(md5(microtime()), mt_rand(0, 30), 2);
$path = 'uploads/'.$dir . '/' . $name; # по этому пути сохраняем фотку

if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
if (!mkdir('uploads/'.$dir, 0, true)) {
    MessageSend(1, 'Директория не создана.', '/'.$Row['type'].'/photo/id/'.$Param['id']);
}
$imagick = new Imagick($photo); 
$imagick->setCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$imagick->setCompressionQuality(90); 
$imagick->stripImage(); 
$imagick->thumbnailImage(1024, 0);
$imagick->writeImage($photo);
if (move_uploaded_file($photo, $path)) {
    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `photo` VALUES ('', '$_SESSION[USER_ID]', '$_SESSION[object_id]', '$path')");
    unset ($_SESSION['object_id']);
} 
else {
    MessageSend(1, 'Фотографии не загружены.', '/'.$Row['type'].'/photo/id/'.$Param['id']);
}
}
else {
MessageSend(1, 'Ошибка.','/object/photo/');
}
```

И есть такая функция создания превьюшек

```
var previewWidth = 150, // ширина превью
previewHeight = 150, // высота превью
selectedFiles = {},// объект, в котором будут храниться выбранные файлы
queue = [],
image = new Image(),
imgLoadHandler,
isProcessing = false,
errorMsg,
previewPhotoContainer = document.querySelector('#preview-photo'); // контейнер, в котором будут отображаться превью

            // Когда пользователь выбрал файлы, обрабатываем их
$('input[type=file][id=uploadfiles]').on('change', function() {
    var newFiles = $(this)[0].files; // массив с выбранными файлами
        for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
        var file = newFiles[i];
        if (selectedFiles[file.name] != undefined) continue;
        if ( errorMsg = validateFile(file) ) {
            alert(errorMsg);
            return;
        }
        selectedFiles[file.name] = file;
        queue.push(file);
    }
    $(this).val('');
    processQueue(); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюр
});
var validateFile = function(file) {
    if ( !file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/) ) {
        return 'Фотография должна быть в формате jpg, png или gif';
    }
};
var listen = function(element, event, fn) {
    return element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
};
    // Создание миниатюры
var processQueue = function() {
    if (isProcessing) { 
        return; 
    }
    if (queue.length == 0) {
        isProcessing = false;
        return;
    }
    isProcessing = true;
    var file = queue.pop(); // Берем один файл из очереди
    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var spanDel = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'img');
    spanDel.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
    spanDel.innerHTML = 'Удалить';

    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(spanDel);
    li.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);
    image.removeEventListener('load', imgLoadHandler, false);
    // создаем миниатюру
    imgLoadHandler = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        span.appendChild(canvas);
        isProcessing = false;
        setTimeout(processQueue, 200); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюры для следующего изображения
    };
    // Выводим миниатюру в контейнере previewPhotoContainer
    previewPhotoContainer.appendChild(li);
    listen(image, 'load', imgLoadHandler);
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
};
// Удаление фотографии
$(document).on('click', '#preview-photo li span.delete', function() {
    var fileId = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');
    if (selectedFiles[fileId] != undefined) delete selectedFiles[fileId]; // Удаляем файл из объекта selectedFiles
    $(this).parents('li').remove(); // Удаляем превью
});
```

Превьюшки создается в `base64` и никак не привязаны к тем, что сохраняются на сервере и заносятся в базу. Самый простой способ (на мой взгляд и не знаю будет ли он работать) это передать в эти строки

```
li.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

значения из php

`$name` вместо `file.name` и `$path` вместо `URL.createObjectURL(file)`.

Но как это сделать не знаю. Может есть у кого какие мысли по этому поводу!

Comment: ты попробуй переименовать картинку как идентификатор новой строки. Например 1.jpg, 2.jpg.  Когда будешь вытаскивать тогда просто:  $id.".jpg"